# Exceptions in database model, how do I handle it?

Tags: php

I am creating a model for a small PHP application. This will utilize PDO to communicate with a MySQL-server. I have understood that the recommended error mode is the one which throws exceptions, as this allows for graceful error handling. But I don't understand how I should handle these exceptions?

Technically, it is easy, but let me give you an example:

```
class Model()
{
    private $host = "localhost", 
            $user = "",
            $pass = "",
            $DBH;


    function __construct()
    {
        try
        { 
            $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

            $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        }  
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {  
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

If I create an object Model in my controller, and it fails, I have no way of handling this in my controller, right? Or what happens when I create that object, "new Model" returns false?

Excuse me for being a newbie, but I want to be able to handle any exceptions also from other functions in the model. How should I go about this? I need to be able to know if something went wrong in my controller and be able to do the appropriate thing there.

Comment: try look php manual regarding `set_exception_handler`

Comment: Hm... that sounds like a really ugly solution. If I understand this correct, I would let my model throw lots of exceptions and then I would catch them in the controller or something? Also, after that callback function has executed it will terminate the script so it really isn't any improvement. I want to be able to say, in the controller, "hey, DB failed, let's do this instead." and then serve the page as usual but without the DB stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your controller to catch the exception as well, you can always rethrow it after logging.

```
class Model()
{
    ...

    function __construct()
    {
        try
        { 
            ...
        }  
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {  
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends entirely on what the error_log function does.

You can return the exception. 
You can simply die after logging the error (presumably if your application can't hit the DB then theres no graceful recovery). 
You can return a custom exception via throw();

It's really just your preference.

Comment: Isn't there like a best practice? Also, I might want to go ahead and serve the page (actually I do) even if I can't use the DB. But I will want to know, in my controller, that the model is not working so that I can skip that portion of the site which requires DB info. error_log just writes the error to a log file.